# SQL - Problem with a query for stock to date

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench

The image below illustrates the schema of my query. I would like to obtain the stock of marbles that I have when I am a park (park 1 or park 6) on a given date.

[image: img1]

- @date = '2023-12-20'
- table LettreVoiture (idlv, lieuxdepart,lieuxarriver, datedepart, datearrive)
- table LettreVoitureLigne(idlvr, idlv, idbille)
- table bille (idbille)

--------------- PARC 1 -------------

- depart: '2023-12-12'
- arrivée: '2023-12-20'

----------------- Parc 6 ------------------

- arrivé : '2023-12-14'
- depart : '2023-12-18'

obtain the marbles which have arrived in park 1 until 2023-12-20 by removing the marbles which have left up to this day in this same park`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.idpreparation AS idb, es.description_essence, 
    pp.codebar_grume, pp.num_colis,    
    b.affectation_bil, l.description_licence, 
    l.idlicence, pp.longueur_prepa AS longu,
    pp.diam_gb_prepa AS GB, pp.diam_pb_prepa AS PB, 
    pp.volume_prepa AS volume, '', 'Arrivée par LV' AS etat,
    LV.datelv, LV.datearriverlv AS datess, LV.idlv 
FROM 
    lettre_voiture_ligne_grume LVR
JOIN
    lettre_voiture_grume LV ON LV.idlv = LVR.idlv 
JOIN 
    billage b ON b.idpreparation = LVR.idbille 
JOIN 
    preparation_pied pp ON pp.idpreparation = b.idpreparation 
LEFT JOIN 
    essence es ON es.idessence = pp.idessence
LEFT JOIN 
    licence l ON l.idlicence = pp.idlicence
WHERE 
    LV.datearriverlv <= '2023-12-20' 
    AND LV.lieuxarrive = 6
    AND pp.idpreparation not in (select idbille 
                                 from lettre_voiture_ligne_grume LVR 
                                 join lettre_voiture_grume LV on LV.idlv = LVR.idlv 
                                 where LV.lieuxdepart = 6 and LV.datelv <= '2023-12-20')
```

Comment: Voting to close because although question is in english query isn't..

Comment: This question has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77758205/request-for-stock

Comment: Why should a few names using some non-English terms make it impossible to follow the query logic?  What is missing is "sample data" and "expected result"  ("échantillon de données" et "résultat attendu")